# How to start a new job if the old job has finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I am writing a small game and I want to decouple my renderer with the main loop. In the main loop I want to do update my input and I don't want to wait until my renderer has finished drawing, but that means I only want to issue draw commands if the renderer has finished drawing.

I need a way to know if the old rendering job has finished, so that I can start a new one.

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
struct ready
{
  bool is_ready;
  std::mutex m;
  void set(bool b)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
    is_ready = b;
  }
  operator bool()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
    return is_ready;
  }
  ready()
    : is_ready(true)
  {
  }
};

int
main()
{
  auto service = std::make_shared<asio::io_service>();
  auto w = std::make_shared<asio::io_service::work>(*service);
  std::thread t1([&] { service->run(); });
  std::thread t2([&] { service->run(); });
  auto ready_sp = std::make_shared<ready>();
  while (ready_sp) {
    if (*ready_sp) {
      ready_sp->set(false);
      service->dispatch([ready_sp] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "Draw on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id()
                  << std::endl;

        ready_sp->set(true);
      });
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    std::cout << "Doing other stuff" << std::endl;
  }
  w.reset();
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

Is this roughly how I would do this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know, it seems that way.

Comment: Just trying to think of a neat way to do this for you, but first some questions.
a) should the renderer render continuously (but sequentially), or only when told that it can? 
b) is the intent of the second io-service thread for rendering or other game functions?

Comment: @RichardHodges a) Only when it can, I don't want to queue up rendering commands. b) I was just testing things out. Initially I thought I would create a "thread pool" and then distribute my jobs to all available threads, but I think it would probably better to have a single thread for the renderer.

Comment: @MaikKlein answer provided with complete, working example.

Comment: @MaikKlein for the sake of interest, provided second answer to demonstrate how to provide a second scene-renderer running in a third thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here is an example of how I might approach it.

This code has one thread for rendering (but we could use more) and uses the main thread for playing the game.

I have split the code into a number of *concerns*:

`scene` is the data that describes the scene state

`render` is the free function that renders the scene. It is unaware of threading, locks, mutexes or memory management.

`renderer` is an object that renders scenes in its own thread, but only when told to.

`scene_update` encapsulates the concept of a number of incremental updates to the scene, but the renderer should only be asked to render once all increments have completed - i.e. an atomic update.

This example simulates a scene update calculation taking 300ms but the actual rendering takes 1s. Therefore we should see 1 render per ~3 updates.

Hopefully you'll agree that since the entire program uses *value semantics* and encapsulates all memory management and threading issues, the main body of the program is very easy to read.

Here is main:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // create my scene
    scene my_scene;

    // instantiate my renderer
    renderer my_renderer;

    // tell the renderer that the scene may be rendered
    my_renderer.notify(my_scene);

    // ... while it is doing that...
    // ... lets make our hero march across the wilderness
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0 ; y < 10 ; ++y)
        {
            // perform a scene update. the calculations for this update
            // take 300ms (faster than the renderer)
            scene_update u(my_scene, my_renderer);
            {
                my_scene.data().hero_x = x;
                my_scene.data().hero_y = y;
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
            }
            // tell the renderer that there is a new scene to render
            u.commit();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

similarly `render` is very simple:

```
void render(const scene& s)
{
    using namespace std;

    const auto& data = s.data();

    cout << "the hero is at ";
    cout.flush();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

    cout << data.hero_x << ", ";
    cout.flush();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

    cout << data.hero_y << '\n';
    cout.flush();
}
```

Here is the complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>


//
// a simple scene object with *value semantics*
// the actual scene data is stored in an inner class, an instance of which is maintained by a unique_ptr
// we could have used a shared_ptr but there is no reason to since we will be taking copies of the scene
// data in order to render it out of line.
// doing it this way means that although the copy might be expensive, it is only performed once
// moves are extremely fast
struct scene
{
    // a type to allow us to create an unitialised scene explicitly
    struct none_type {};

    // a flag object
    static constexpr const none_type none = none_type();

    // this is the actual expensive scene data (simulated)
    struct expensive_large_scene_data
    {
        int hero_x = 0,
        hero_y = 0;
    };

    // a printer function (to help debugging)
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const expensive_large_scene_data& s)
    {
        os << "(" << s.hero_x << ", " << s.hero_y << ")";
        return os;
    }

    // construct empty
    scene(none_type) {
        // no not initialise the pointer
    }

    // construct and initialise a default scene
    scene() : _data(std::make_unique<expensive_large_scene_data>()) {}

    // copy constructor must explicitly clone the pointer (if populated)
    scene(const scene& r)
    : _data(r
            ? std::make_unique<expensive_large_scene_data>(r.data())
            : nullptr)
    {}

    // move constructor
    scene(scene&& r)
    : _data(std::move(r._data))
    {}

    // copy-assignment - take care here too.
    scene& operator=(const scene& r)
    {
        _data = r
        ? std::make_unique<expensive_large_scene_data>(r.data())
        : nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    // move-assignment is simple
    scene& operator=(scene&& r)
    {
        _data = std::move(r._data);
        return *this;
    }

    // no need for a destructor - we're using unique_ptr

    bool valid() const {
        return bool(_data.get());
    }

    // convertible to bool so we can check whether it is empty easily

    operator bool() const {
        return valid();
    }

    void reset() {
        _data.reset();
    }

    // accessor

    const expensive_large_scene_data& data() const {
        assert(_data.get());
        return *_data;
    }

    expensive_large_scene_data& data() {
        assert(_data.get());
        return *_data;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<expensive_large_scene_data> _data;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const scene& s)
{
    return os << s.data();
}


// a function that renders a scene
// this one takes a second to complete
void render(const scene& s)
{
    using namespace std;

    const auto& data = s.data();

    cout << "the hero is at ";
    cout.flush();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

    cout << data.hero_x << ", ";
    cout.flush();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

    cout << data.hero_y << '\n';
    cout.flush();
}

// the renderer
struct renderer
{
    using mutex_type = std::mutex;
    using lock_type = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

    // start thread in constructor - do not copy this object (you can't anyway because of the mutex)
    renderer()
    : _render_thread(std::bind(&renderer::loop, this))
    {}

    // shut down cleanly on destruction
    ~renderer()
    {
        auto lock = lock_type(_mutex);
        _cancelled = true;
        lock.unlock();

        if (_render_thread.joinable())
        {
            _render_thread.join();
        }
    }

    // notify the renderer that a new scene is ready
    void notify(const scene& s)
    {
        auto lock = lock_type(_mutex);
        _pending_scene = s;
        lock.unlock();
        _cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    void loop()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            auto lock = lock_type(_mutex);
            _cv.wait(lock, [this] {
                // wait for either a cancel event or for a new scene to be ready
                return _cancelled or _pending_scene;
            });

            if (_cancelled) return;

            // move the pending scene to our scene-render buffer - this is very cheap
            _current_scene = std::move(_pending_scene);
            _pending_scene.reset();
            lock.unlock();

            // unlock early to allow mainline code to continue


            // now take our time rendering the scene
            render(_current_scene);
            _current_scene.reset();
        }
    }

private:
    mutex_type _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    bool _cancelled = false;
    scene _pending_scene = scene(scene::none);
    scene _current_scene = scene(scene::none);
    std::thread _render_thread;
};

// an object to connect a scene update 'transaction' with the renderer
struct scene_update
{
    scene_update(scene& s, renderer& r)
    : _s(s), _r(r) {}

    void commit()
    {
        _r.notify(_s);
    }

    scene& _s;
    renderer& _r;
};



int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // create my scene
    scene my_scene;

    // instantiate my renderer
    renderer my_renderer;

    // tell the renderer that the scene may be rendered
    my_renderer.notify(my_scene);

    // ... while it is doing that...
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0 ; y < 10 ; ++y)
        {
            // perform a scene update. the calculations for this update
            // take 300ms (faster than the renderer)
            scene_update u(my_scene, my_renderer);
            {
                my_scene.data().hero_x = x;
                my_scene.data().hero_y = y;
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
            }
            // tell the renderer that there is a new scene to render
            u.commit();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
the hero is at 0, 0            
the hero is at 0, 2         <<-- note the missing updates
the hero is at 0, 5         <<-- because rendering takes longer
the hero is at 0, 8         <<-- than calculation
the hero is at 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks, `condition_variable` is something I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches to this. The specific approach you will need depends on particular minutiae of your entire application. The small code samples you posted is not really enough to determine all the details. Take the following as two general approaches that you will need to refine to come up with your application-specific solution:

#### Joinable threads

Use `std::thread::joinable()` to check if a particular thread has finished. If so, you can `join()` the thread immediately, and start your next thread.

#### Detached Threads

The polling-style approach is often cumbersome to use in most situations, where an event-based approach will work better. The typical solution here is that a thread will have a `std::mutex`-protected flag, typically paired with a `std::condition_variable`. The thread sets the flag (and optionally signals the condition variable) just before the thread terminates.

In this case, often nobody cares to `join()` the thread when it finishes, so the thread always gets kicked off as a detached thread, and its termination gets checked via the flag (although there isn't really anything wrong with continuing to use a joinable thread, as long as the first time the flag gets checked, and it's set, the checker is responsible for joining the just-terminated thread).

Of course, there's a small window of time after the thread that's about to terminate sets the flag, and when it actually terminates, when the thread is technically running, but this is usually irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Continued in a second answer.

This version expands upon the idea of decoupling the renderer from the actual draw function.

It creates two renderers, each living in its own thread. Each renderer is responsible for running its own view.

In this case, we have improved the game by offering the player a first-person view and an overall map-view. Because the map view is smaller, it takes less time to render.

Because each view is running in its own thread, with its own copy of the scene data, the smaller view can benefit by updating more frequently - but still not more frequently than the actual atomic updates to the scene model.

Here's the modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>


//
// a simple scene object with *value semantics*
// the actual scene data is stored in an inner class, an instance of which is maintained by a unique_ptr
// we could have used a shared_ptr but there is no reason to since we will be taking copies of the scene
// data in order to render it out of line.
// doing it this way means that although the copy might be expensive, it is only performed once
// moves are extremely fast
struct scene
{
    // a type to allow us to create an unitialised scene explicitly
    struct none_type {};

    // a flag object
    static constexpr const none_type none = none_type();

    // this is the actual expensive scene data (simulated)
    struct expensive_large_scene_data
    {
        int hero_x = 0,
        hero_y = 0;
    };

    // a printer function (to help debugging)
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const expensive_large_scene_data& s)
    {
        os << "(" << s.hero_x << ", " << s.hero_y << ")";
        return os;
    }

    // construct empty
    scene(none_type) {
        // no not initialise the pointer
    }

    // construct and initialise a default scene
    scene() : _data(std::make_unique<expensive_large_scene_data>()) {}

    // copy constructor must explicitly clone the pointer (if populated)
    scene(const scene& r)
    : _data(r
            ? std::make_unique<expensive_large_scene_data>(r.data())
            : nullptr)
    {}

    // move constructor
    scene(scene&& r)
    : _data(std::move(r._data))
    {}

    // copy-assignment - take care here too.
    scene& operator=(const scene& r)
    {
        _data = r
        ? std::make_unique<expensive_large_scene_data>(r.data())
        : nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    // move-assignment is simple
    scene& operator=(scene&& r)
    {
        _data = std::move(r._data);
        return *this;
    }

    // no need for a destructor - we're using unique_ptr

    bool valid() const {
        return bool(_data.get());
    }

    // convertible to bool so we can check whether it is empty easily

    operator bool() const {
        return valid();
    }

    void reset() {
        _data.reset();
    }

    // accessor

    const expensive_large_scene_data& data() const {
        assert(_data.get());
        return *_data;
    }

    expensive_large_scene_data& data() {
        assert(_data.get());
        return *_data;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<expensive_large_scene_data> _data;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const scene& s)
{
    return os << s.data();
}


// helper function to serialise access to cout
void emit(const std::string& display_id, const std::string& s)
{
    static std::mutex _m;
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(_m);
    std::cout << display_id << " : " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
}

// this renderer renders the scene from the perspective of the hero. it takes a second to draw
struct first_person_view
{
    // a function that renders a scene
    // this one takes a second to complete
    void operator()(const scene& s) const
    {
        using namespace std;

        const auto& data = s.data();
        std::ostringstream ss;


        ss << "I am at ";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

        ss << data.hero_x << ", ";

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

        ss << data.hero_y;
        emit("first_person_view", ss.str());
    }
};

// this renderer renders the scene from the perspective of a top-dowm map. it takes half a second to draw
struct map_view
{
    // a function that renders a scene
    // this one takes half a second to complete
    void operator()(const scene& s) const
    {
        using namespace std;

        const auto& data = s.data();
        std::ostringstream ss;

        ss << "the hero is at ";
        ss << data.hero_x << ", ";

        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

        ss << data.hero_y;
        emit("map_view", ss.str());
    }
};



// the renderer
template<class RenderFunction>
struct renderer
{
    using mutex_type = std::mutex;
    using lock_type = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

    using render_function = RenderFunction;

    // start thread in constructor - do not copy this object (you can't anyway because of the mutex)
    renderer(render_function f)
    : _render_function(std::move(f))
    {
        // defer thread start until all data members initialised
        _render_thread = std::thread(std::bind(&renderer::loop, this));
    }

    // shut down cleanly on destruction
    ~renderer()
    {
        auto lock = lock_type(_mutex);
        _cancelled = true;
        lock.unlock();

        if (_render_thread.joinable())
        {
            _render_thread.join();
        }
    }

    // notify the renderer that a new scene is ready
    void notify(const scene& s)
    {
        auto lock = lock_type(_mutex);
        _pending_scene = s;
        lock.unlock();
        _cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    void loop()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            auto lock = lock_type(_mutex);
            _cv.wait(lock, [this] {
                // wait for either a cancel event or for a new scene to be ready
                return _cancelled or _pending_scene;
            });

            if (_cancelled) return;

            // move the pending scene to our scene-render buffer - this is very cheap
            _current_scene = std::move(_pending_scene);
            _pending_scene.reset();
            lock.unlock();

            // unlock early to allow mainline code to continue


            // now take our time rendering the scene
            _render_function(_current_scene);
            _current_scene.reset();
        }
    }

private:
    render_function _render_function;
    mutex_type _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    bool _cancelled = false;
    scene _pending_scene = scene(scene::none);
    scene _current_scene = scene(scene::none);
    std::thread _render_thread;
};

template<class...R>
void notify(const scene& the_scene, R&... each_renderer)
{
    using expand = int[];
    (void) expand { 0, (each_renderer.notify(the_scene), 0)... };
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // create my scene
    scene my_scene;

    // instantiate my renderer
    renderer<first_person_view> my_renderer { first_person_view() };
    renderer<map_view> map_renderer { map_view() };

    // tell the renderer that the scene may be rendered
    notify(my_scene, my_renderer, map_renderer);

    // ... while it is doing that...
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0 ; y < 10 ; ++y)
        {
            // perform a scene update. the calculations for this update
            // take 300ms (faster than the renderer)
            my_scene.data().hero_x = x;
            my_scene.data().hero_y = y;
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
            // tell the renderer that there is a new scene to render
            notify(my_scene, my_renderer, map_renderer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

... and the example output:

```
...snip
first_person_view : I am at 7, 5
map_view : the hero is at 7, 7
map_view : the hero is at 7, 8
map_view : the hero is at 8, 0
first_person_view : I am at 7, 8
map_view : the hero is at 8, 2
map_view : the hero is at 8, 3
first_person_view : I am at 8, 2
map_view : the hero is at 8, 5
...snip
```